# Unexpected token . when importing .css file with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Here is my webpack config

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery), 'eslint-loader']},
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass' },
```

The off thing is, I have another project that is a near copy of this and it works fine. In both cases I import the .css like this.

```
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css'
```

The error:

```
[require-hacker] Trying to load "style.css" as a "*.js"
[1] [piping] can't execute file: /Users/myUser/Projects/fed/bin/server.js
[1] [piping] error given was: /Users/myUser/Projects/fed/node_modules/react-day-picker/lib/style.css:3
[1] .DayPicker {
[1] ^
[1] 
[1] SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
[1]     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
[1]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
[1]     at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
[1]     at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/Users/myUser/Projects/fed/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
[1]     at Object._module2.default._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/myUser/Projects/fed/node_modules/require-hacker/babel-transpiled-modules/require hacker.js:260:68)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
[1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
[1]     at Module._load (module.js:458:3)
[1]     at Function.module._load (/Users/myUser/Projects/fed/node_modules/piping/lib/launcher.js:32:16)
[1] [piping] further repeats of this error will be suppressed...
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a bit of a work around for it. On my project I use the is-in-browser module to get past babel and only import the external stylesheets if the app was running in a browser window, which you could use in your component like this:

```
import isBrowser from 'is-in-browser';

if (isBrowser) {
    require ('react-day-picker/lib/style.css')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

might be because of this

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery), 'eslint-loader']},
```

This only bablifies .jsx files and excludes node modules, you need to add configuration for .js files also and mention not to go inside node modules while the loader is run as can be seen from your stack trace.

something like

```
{ test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery), 'eslint-loader']},
```

Hope it helps :)